# Using a second Ansible server in azure

Tags: azure, automation, ansible

I’m a university student and we are getting started with service automation and getting to know Ansible.
I’m really love creating playbooks and learning more about Ansible.
But I have to automate an multitier network in azure.
I have already created and tested my playbooks(on my local Ubuntu server) for creating my azure network, subnets, nsgs, multiple virtual machines. And i have my playbooks that i want to run on these created VMs.
I will have 2 virtual machines with a public ip, 1 load balancer and 1 steppingstone server. And only the steppingstone server can be used with SSH.
But how do I get to play my playbooks from my local Ansible server in my azure environment?
Can I give this as a task when I create the VM or can i use a server with public ip in azure that I can use to send the right playbook to the right server?

I have done some research but I don’t know if I’m searching wrong but I can’t find how to start

Answer (score 2):

fir running ansible playbooks on Azure VMs from your local Ansible serve, you can
use the Azure Dynamic Inventory script for Ansible to fetch VM details from Azure Resource Manager.

don't forget to configure your Ansible inventory to use the Azure Dynamic Inventory script.

Organize your playbooks into roles based on functionality (e.g., webserver, database.

Tag your VMs to specify which playbook or tasks should run on each VM, use SSH keys, and configure Azure credentials securely.

to learn more you can visit the documentation of azure and in the search bar you can find the info you need after a search. link below

h[ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=ansible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=ansible)